# Castle dynamic proxy not creating an implementation for inherited interface method

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a base interface that is inherited by several other interfaces.  This interface has one method:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBase
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<short> GetShorts();
}
```

I then, of course, have an inheriting interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUseful : IBase
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<MyObject> GetMyObjects(MyInput input);
}
```

I have a class that serves as a generic interceptor for interfaces in order to provide a simple way to call services without extra setup:

```
public class ServiceInvoker<T> : DynamicObject, IInterceptor
    where T : class
{
    // ...
    public T Client { get { return (dynamic)this; } }
    // ...
}
```

I want to be able to call any service that implements `IBase`, so I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class BaseCaller
{
    private readonly IBase _base;
    public BaseCaller(IBase base) { _base = base; }
    public List<short> GetShorts() { return _base.GetShorts(); }
}
```

I construct `BaseCaller` basically like this:

```
var si = new ServiceInvoker<IUseful>();
var bc = new BaseCaller(si.Client);
```

The problem comes when I make a call to `GetShorts` and it calls `_base.GetShorts`:

> MissingMethodException
>
> Method 'MyApp.IUseful.GetSubNumbers' not found.

When I hover over `_base`, I can see the interceptor, and I can see that `token_GetSubNumbers` exists.  I can cast `_base` to `IUseful` and call `GetMyObjects` successfully; I just can't call `GetShorts`.  It looks like Castle isn't implementing `IBase`.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: castle configuration?

Comment: @giammin:  None, so I guess default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work, so going with it unless someone provides a better solution:

I removed the inheritence of `IBase` and just use it directly with a `ServiceInvoker<IBase>`.  The services now have to implement `IBase` directly and expose an endpoint for it, but it works.